# From Julia DateTime to Int64 and back

Tags: datetime, type-conversion, julia, hdf5

In order to store a DateTime array to a HDF5 database, I first converted each DateTime to Int64 and did the reverse upon retrieval. The code looks as follows:

```
using Dates
a = Array{DateTime, 1}(undef, 2)
a[1] = DateTime("2020-01-01")
a[2] = DateTime("2020-01-02")

# Convert to Int64 array
msecs = [d.instant.periods.value for d in a]

# Code to store to hdf5 here (skipped for now)

# Code to retrieve from hdf5 here (skipped for now)

# Convert back to array of DateTime
b = [DateTime(0) + Millisecond(msec) for msec in msecs]
```

- Question1: Is it the best way to convert back and forth between DateTime and Int64?
- Question2: Can we directly store DateTime in hdf5 without conversion or is this the way to go?

Comment: I guess a less convoluted way to implement your current solution would be to use datetime2unix and unix2datetime. I'm not sure about more efficient storage of dates in HDF5. (EDIT: but it uses floats instead of ints)

Comment: @FrançoisFévotte Thanks for your response. Would this be the best method in the long term in view of the limitations of Unix time. Moreover, a simple datetime_to_ms or to_int64 would have seems to make sense.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what the best solution would be. Let's wait and see if someone more knowledgeable chimes in with other ideas.

Comment: There is also: `i = Dates.value(convert(Millisecond, dt))` and `dt = convert(DateTime, Millisecond(i))`, which is the exact equivalent to what you're doing, but relies more on the public API for the conversion/promotion of DateTime values.